# Python variable redefinition in a function

Tags: python, function, variables

I have a problem with the python code.
Indeed, I want to change the value of a global variable through a function like this:

```
myVar = True # default value
def myFunct():
   myVar = False
```

The problem is with Python, you can't change the value of the global variable by a function. So anyone have a solutuion ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myVar = True # default value
def myFunct():
   global myVar
   myVar= False

myFunct()  
print(myVar)
```

Output:

```
False
```

Explanation:

When you want to access the global variable inside a function access that variable using "global" keyword. And then you can update that variable.

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: @MrLeeh Added relevant explanation

Comment: @Julien Duvart: Is this what you are expecting ?

Comment: Yes ! Thank you very much.  It's work !

Comment: That sounds great. Please confirm the answer so that it will help others

Comment: @kvmahesh oh sorry yes !